# .NET Equivalents to Java Crypto stuff

Tags: java, .net, cryptography

Could anybody tell me what the equivalent .NET classes/methods are to the following Java methods:

```
decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
decryptCipher.init(2, getKey(0));
decryptCipher.doFinal(data);
```

where getKey() returns an object of type SecretKeySpec (data is dummy):

```
public static Key getKey(int cipher) {
    if (cipher == 0) {
      return new SecretKeySpec(new byte[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, "DES");
    }
    return new SecretKeySpec(new byte[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 }, "DES");
  }
```

Many thanks

Tony

Answer (score 1):

The actual class which provides DES cryptography: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.descryptoserviceprovider.aspx
In addition, you may want to read this up :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92f9ye3s.aspx